# Actionscript 3 countdown timer won't display time in textfield AND nothing happens when timer reaches 0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer, textfield

I created a game in AS3 using a tutorial written for AS2 but I can't get the timer working correctly. The game contains 3 frames, a start screen, game loop, and end screen. the timer starts on frame 2, and counts down (tested this with a trace). When the timer reaches 0 I want to go to frame 3 which is the end game screen but my code isn't working.

```
var fl_SecondsToCountDown:Number = 30;

var fl_CountDownTimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(1000, fl_SecondsToCountDown);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_CountDownTimerHandler);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance.start();
theTimer.text = String(fl_SecondsToCountDown);

function fl_CountDownTimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{

    if(fl_SecondsToCountDown == 0){;
        gotoAndPlay(3);
    }else{

    trace(fl_SecondsToCountDown + " seconds");
    fl_SecondsToCountDown--;
    }
}
```

My second problem is that ny timer (theTimer) doesn't show the time.

EDIT:

```
var running:Boolean = new Boolean();
running = false;
var time:Number = new Number();
var fl_SecondsToCountDown:Number = 30;
var fl_CountDownTimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(1000, fl_SecondsToCountDown);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_CountDownTimerHandler);
fl_CountDownTimerInstance.start();

function fl_CountDownTimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    time=fl_SecondsToCountDown;

    if(time == 0){
        running = false;
        trace(running);
        gotoAndStop(3);
    }else{

    trace(fl_SecondsToCountDown + " seconds");
    fl_SecondsToCountDown--;
    theTimer.text = String(fl_SecondsToCountDown);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that theTimer exists when you set the value?

Comment: there's a typo in your program: if(fl_SecondsToCountDown == 0){;, also your textField isn't going to update itself when you change the fl_SecondsToCountDown variable.

Comment: Wasn't a typo rather a copy/paste error:) Thanks though. fl_SecondsToCountDown did work. I had to move it's placement and I had to recreate the textfield. the ttorial I was following for AS2 said to convert the textfield into an mc. leaving it as a textfield was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you update `theTimer` inside the `fl_CountDownTimerHandler` function, otherwise it will only update when it's initialized.

And my guess is that your last countdown check isn't being fired because it'll never run the event again when `fl_SecondsToCountDown` is 0 already. Add some more checks with `trace` and it will be easier to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks zeh I got the timer to display. I was unable to get my countdown check to fire. I added what I believe to be the checks you were talking about. The trace(running) didn't rexecute

Comment: Figured it out. The timer never actually reaches 0, it stops after 1 s I changed the if statement to if(time == 1){...gotoAndStop(...);